# How to get Google to re-index a page after removing noindex metatag?

Tags: web-crawler, sitemap, meta-tags, google-search-console, noindex

By accident, I had put `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` into lots of pages on my domain. I have now removed this meta-tag, but how can I get these pages to be re-indexed by Google? Any tip?

I have tried re-submitting my sitemap.xml in Webmaster Tools, but I'm not sure if it works.

Also, if Google will re-index, how long do I have to wait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google usually fairly quickly crawls your pages. Inclusion into index is a bit slower, and getting reasonable search rank takes time.

Look at your web server log to confirm that google bot did crawl your pages, you can search for exact page in google and it usually comes up, but to start showing up for relevant terms takes time.

For example if you search for 'dilution calculator' it is unlikely that my page will come up, but if you search for 'bugaco.com dilution calculator'
the page on the site is first hit [Dilution Calculator - Bugaco](http://http:www.bugaco.com/calculators/dilution_calculator.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my problem is a bit more spesific. Google bot visited my webserver last week, and crawled my 7000 pages. At that time, there was an error on the page, including the noindex meta tag in the head section. Resulting no pages was indexed. Now, I have removed the noindex meta-tag, and want google to re-index the 7000 pages on my site.

Comment: I get typically about 100 pages crawled by google per day, but again to get into the index takes time. Submitting the sitemap may be your best option or use fetch as google & submit to index.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I see today that Google have started to index some of my pages again, so I see hope in the tunnel. Thank you for the help.